# Service-Now API, python PUT snippet for assigning incident to me

Tags: python, rest, servicenow

I am working with https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/utah/rest/c_TableAPI

and I get a list of incidents I need for the next step.

Next step is: I need to assign certain incidents to me. I wonder if anyone could help with service-now REST API.

I need an example for assigning a given incident to myself.

21/11/2023, when I try this snippet (according to https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/reference/api/utah/rest/c_TableAPI#table-PUT):

```
id_incident = '49akkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk3'
url = 'https://PPPPPPPPP.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident/{}'.format(id_incident)

user = "OOOOOOO"
pwd = "OOOOOOO"

# Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}
data = {"assigned_to":"12cccccccccccccccccca"}

# Do the HTTP request
response = requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, data=data, timeout=None)
res = response.json()
```

I get this error printing res:

```
{'error': {'message': 'Exception while reading request',
  'detail': 'The payload is not valid JSON.'},
 'status': 'failure'}
```

Comment: The PUT on the page contains a CURL command for doing exactly that. Check it's data element and you know what to send.

Comment: @JustLudo thank you. Only, I don't have to specify 'urgency' nor to add comments. Hope the data I send is ok just as data = {'assigned_to':'1XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXa'}

Comment: Y/w, only 1 way to find out I guess. If it is/was, don't forget to answer your own question so it can be found in related questions in the future.

Comment: @JustLudo, no it is not working either ways. I attach update

Comment: Use the payload as described in the example then. The structure must be there but the fields can maybe be left empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the API documentation, I believe that the API requests a JSON- formatted string in the body. Perhaps you could try the following :

```
response = requests.put(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers, json=data, timeout=None)
```